# Différence between two date using JsDatePick [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

i want to calculate the difference in days between two dates using JsDatePick
so this is my two pick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"field", cellColorScheme:"deepblue", dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d" });
    new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"field2", cellColorScheme:"deepblue", dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d" });};
</script>
```

---

the date selected is saved on this textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="field" name="dateDebut"  placeholder="Date début"    />
<input type="text" id="field2" name="dateFin"  placeholder="Date Fin"   />
```

---

i dont know how to calcule the difference day between this two days
,some one help me please, and i want to print the number of difference day on this textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="Difference" name=Difference" class="span3"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you're using a plugin please tag it in question or give a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inside the script tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"field", cellColorScheme:"deepblue", dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d" });
        new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"field2", cellColorScheme:"deepblue", dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d" });
    };

    function getValue(field){
        console.log("getValue()"+document.getElementById(field).value);
        return document.getElementById(field).value;
    }

    function setValue(field,value){
        document.getElementById(field).value = value;
    }

    function showDifferenceInDays(field,field2,fieldOut){
        var fieldDate = new Date(getValue(field));
        var field2Date = new Date(getValue(field2));

        var fieldMilliseconds = fieldDate.getTime();
        //console.log(fieldMilliseconds);

        var field2Milliseconds = field2Date.getTime();
        //console.log(field2Milliseconds);

        var diffMilliseconds = fieldMilliseconds-field2Milliseconds;
        //console.log(diffMilliseconds);

        var millisecondsInADay = 1000*60*60*24;

        //console.log(diffMilliseconds/millisecondsInADay);
        setValue(fieldOut,(diffMilliseconds/millisecondsInADay));
    }
</script>
```

**Inside the body tag:**

```
<input type="text" id="field" name="dateDebut"  placeholder="Date début"    />
<input type="text" id="field2" name="dateFin"  placeholder="Date Fin"   />
<input type="text" id="Difference" name=Difference" class="span3"/>
<input type="button" value="Show Difference" onClick="showDifferenceInDays('field','field2','Difference')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDays(d1, d2) {
    var time1 = d1.getTime();
    var time2 = d2.getTime();
    return parseInt((time2-time1)/(24*3600*1000));
}

date1 = new Date("6/04/2014")
//Wed Jun 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
date2 = new Date("7/04/2014")
//Fri Jul 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

getDays(date1,date2)
//output 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDays(date1, date2) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    return diffDays;
}

var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field').value);
var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

getDays(date1,date2)
//output 10
```